# create a directive for input file in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have many input files, and for each input file I have a preview div.

The input file accepts only images, so when I select some image I can preview it in the preview div.

I want also when I select some image to create a scope for it dynamically, what I mean is for example if I have this input file :

```
<input id="identityDocument" name="identityDocument"
                 ui-jq="filestyle" type="file" class="filestyle input-lg" ui-options="{
                    buttonText: '{{'ACTIONS.UPLOAD' | translate}}',
                    iconName: 'fa fa-inbox'
                  }"
                 accept="image/*">
```

I want to create a variable for it which called : `$scope.candidature.identityDocument`

This scope variable will contain only the name of the image I've selected, to save it in the database.

I want to use another scope variable which will contain the image data so I can preview it after `onchange` event.

Another thing I want is to get required work on the input file since there is no support for input `type="file"` with the `ng-model` service.

I've done all this and it works as following :

this is my html code for one input :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="identityDocument">{{'FME_CANDIDATURE.PERSONAL_INFORMATIONS.IDENTITY_DOCUMENT' |
            translate}}: </label>
          <input id="identityDocument" name="identityDocument"
                 ui-jq="filestyle" type="file" class="filestyle input-lg" ui-options="{
                    buttonText: '{{'ACTIONS.UPLOAD' | translate}}',
                    iconName: 'fa fa-inbox'
                  }"
                 onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this,'identityDoc')"
                 accept="image/*">
          <p class="help-block" style="color: #ff635d; !important;">
            <span ng-show="step1.identityDocument.$invalid && !step1.identityDocument.$pristine">{{'FME_CANDIDATURE.PERSONAL_INFORMATIONS.IDENTITY_DOCUMENT_ERROR' | translate}}</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
          <h4 class="custom-font text-greensea"><strong>{{'ACTIONS.PREVIEW' | translate}}</strong></h4>
          <div><img ng-src="{{identityDoc}}" class="md-card-image img-responsive img-thumbnail"
                    alt="{{'ERRORS.NO_PHOTO_SELECTED' | translate}}"></div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

in this code I have the input file which only accepts images and when I select some image I call the function `setFile()`, this function will take two arguments, the current input and the name I want to give to it's scope (since ng-model doesn't work).
and I have another div which will contain an `img` to preview the selected image.

And this is the code of `setFile()` function :

```
$scope.setFile = function(element, name) {
      $scope.currentFile = element.files[0];
      let reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(event) {
        //Converts Angular expression into a function, in our case we convert
        //the string we passed as a variable
        //and then assign a value to the parsed string
        $parse(name).assign($scope, event.target.result);
        //the same as above but instead we passing the name of selected image to the candidature object
        $parse('candidature.'+name).assign($scope, element.value.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''));
        $scope.$apply();

      };
      // when the file is read it triggers the onload event above.
      reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
    };
```

so that function takes the input and a string, in that html example I pass the second param as `"identityDocument"`, this function will then create a variable called : `$scope.identityDocument` which will contain the image data to preview, and `$scope.candidature.identityDocument` which will contain the name of the image.

to make required works for this input file I used this directive :

```
app.directive('validFile',function(){
  return {
    require:'ngModel',
    link:function(scope,el,attrs,ngModel){
      //change event is fired when file is selected
      el.bind('change',function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          ngModel.$setViewValue(el.val());
          ngModel.$render();
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

as following :

```
<input ... accept="image/*" valid-file required>
```

Currently this code works perfectly, but I have to use a directive and a function in the controller, my question is can't I only use one directive which can do all that without using that controller function ?

## Edit :

I've added this line `$parse(name+'Upload').assign($scope, element.files[0]);` to the `setFile` function, which I use to upload the file as following :

```
let file = $scope.identityDocUpload;
      let fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('file', file);
      $http.post('http://localhost:8080/fileUpload', fd, {
          transformRequest: angular.identity,
          headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function () {
        })
        .error(function () {
        });
```

Comment: Why don't you use a directive controller?

Comment: @TobiasTimm what do you mean ?

Comment: You could wrap the whole input in a directive and specifiy a controller within the directive.http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-6-using-controllers there you could set the value and directily verify it

Comment: @TobiasTimm but how can I create those dynamic scope variables in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .directive('validFile', validFile);

    validFile.$inject = [];

    function validFile() {
        var directive = {
        link: link,
        controller: ValidFileController,
        scope: {
                fileRead: '=',
            }
        };
        ValidFileController.$inject = ['$scope'];
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            // do UI-things
        }

         function ValidFileController($scope){
            /* jshint validthis: true */
            var vm = this;
            // do controller things
         }
    }

})();
```

This is a directive, with a controller. In that case you can execute your whole logic within one directive and don't need a `ng-controller`.

That `ng-model` doesnt work for `input type="file"` is right, but your accomplished code isn't really great, because you are accessing the `$scope` in the html via it's html attribute.

So your upload technique can be replaced with

```
 element.bind('change', function (changeEvent) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
               scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.fileRead = loadEvent.target.result;
                 });
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
        });
```

For your dynamic model values, you can choose between different approaches, f.e.

```
$scope['yourAttributeName'] = value;
```

or

```
var the_string = 'my.test';
var model = $parse(the_string);
model.assign($scope, 'test');
```

Comment: Updated the answer